# Is there a way to set the maximum speed of particles?

Tags: particles

Using Newtonian physics I'm generally liking the way things are looking, however particles just keep on accelerating to undesirable speeds, even using "drag" and "damping" it starts off well but things ultimately get too fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set limits on their speed by external forces.
ea at some time it will pass such point and thus the effect will be gone.
Though you can enable drag as a self effect.

In the particle system; go to force field settings
enable self effect
set an amount for example 16
set linear drag 1
set quadratic drag 0

Comment: Thanks thats interesting, and seems to work quite well, for others I've used the settings on the particle system: Force Field Settings, check "self effect", Type 1 selected "drag", linear "0.1" and quadratic "0".

Comment: Why linear rather than quadratic? I would have expected quadratic to work better since the drag is proportional to the square of the velocity - so faster particles will experience more drag and hit their terminal veocity quicker.

Comment: apperantly it seams to work on terminal velocity; so once you reach that constant drag keeps it constant, .. well not sure if it is correct, but for all i know the physics is a bit broken in particle physics. At some point soon in blender developement it will get a makeover. (soon as within 2 to 3 years).

Comment: @conspirisi In the example i used some high values so you would see it quickly.

Comment: @user3800527 no worries, thanks for help, just put down some values that worked for me.

Comment: Oké glad it works out, you can mark it as solution so others will know its solved now, and might find their answer here as well.